# Save file and Open file not working in electron application

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm currently developing an Electron app and encountering an issue with the functionality of buttons placed in the navigation bar. Despite implementing event handlers and adjusting the code responsible for file saving and opening logic, the buttons remain unresponsive.

Here is my code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog, Menu } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

let win;

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });

  win.loadFile('editor/index.html');

  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'File',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Open File',
          click: () => {
            dialog.showOpenDialog(win).then(result => {
              if (!result.canceled) {
                fs.readFile(result.filePaths[0], 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                  if(err){
                      console.log("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
                      return;
                  }
                  win.webContents.send('fileData', data);
                });
              }
            });
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'Save File',
          click: () => {
            win.webContents.send('requestSaveFile');
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

ipcMain.on('saveFile', (event, content) => {
  dialog.showSaveDialog(win).then(result => {
    if (!result.canceled) {
      fs.writeFile(result.filePath, content, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log("An error ocurred creating the file "+ err.message);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: With "remain unresponsive" I take it you mean that nothing happens when you click the menu item, right? Do you get any output whatsoever, any error message in the console?